# How can a parameter in a Generic method be assigned to an Integer and a Character class at the same time?

Tags: java, generics, integer, character, generic-method

Why this code isn't showing any compilation error?

```
public class Generic
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Character[] arr3={'a','b','c','d','e','f','g'};
        Integer a=97;
        System.out.println(Non_genre.genMethod(a,arr3));
    }
}

class Non_genre
{
    static<T> boolean genMethod(T x,T[] y)
    {
        int flag=0;
        for(T r:y)
        {
            if(r==x)
                flag++;
        }
        if(flag==0)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

If we write a normal code like this(shown below)

```
public class Hello
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Character arr=65;
        Integer a='A';
        if(arr==a)  //Compilation Error,shows Incompatible types Integer and Character
            System.out.println("True");
    }
}
```

Then why the above above is running fine,how can T be of Integer class and array of T be of Character class at the same time,and if its running then why its not printing true,ASCII vaue of 'a' is 97,so it should print true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the compiler infers `Object` as a type argument for your invocation of

```
Non_genre.genMethod(a, arr3)
```

Within the body of that method

```
static <T> boolean genMethod(T x, T[] y) {
```

your type parameter `T` is unbounded, and so can only be seen as an `Object`.

Since `x` and the elements of `y` are of the same type (`T`), they can be compared just fine.

```
if (r == x)
```

Comment: *You can compare Object values to other Object values just fine*. This sounds a bit incorrect. It should be *You can compare references to each other just fine*

Comment: @Sotirios-But what will be the type of T in for-each loop,and why its printing false?

Comment: @RajMalhotra Because you are using `==`. That checks for identity, not equality.

Comment: @RajMalhotra The type of `T` is `T`. Since it has no bounds, you can only view it as an `Object`, ie. only `Object`'s methods are available.

Comment: If you want type checking to work properly you can call it like this. Non_genre.<Integer>genMethod(a, arr3) which will give you an error as you have now hinted to the compiler that T is an Integer which means arr3 can only be an Integer[]

Comment: @ChetanKinger: The type `Object` is a reference type, so that is redundant

Comment: @newacct So you are saying that the statement *You can compare Object values to other Object values just fine* is correct?